# Does Stealth Spray work while riding Basculegion?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

The description for Stealth Spray says:

> When used in the field, this spray muffles the sound of your footsteps and makes wild Pokémon less likely to notice you for a short time.

Does the Stealth Spray have any effect while swimming through the water with Basculegion? Or does it only work while on land?

Comment: [this](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/314257-pokemon-legends-arceus/79905126?page=3) post says they do work in the water, but no evidence to back it up

Comment: Same [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PokemonLegendsArceus/comments/sgsuop/how_are_you_supposed_to_catch_pok%C3%A9mon_in_water/), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PokemonLegendsArceus/comments/spfw4t/how_do_i_sneak_up_on_water_pokemon/) and [here](https://www.touchtapplay.com/can-you-use-smoke-bombs-in-the-water-in-pokemon-legends-arceus-answered/).

Comment: I’ll be honest, I’ve never found stealth spray to be worth much … smoke bombs are way better in any case.  I can’t tell if it works in water since it doesn’t seem to help much anyway…